# The user option doesn't seem to work when running linux containers on windows server 2019

Tags: docker, linux-containers, windows-server-2019

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN mkdir /usr/custom
ADD script.sh /usr/custom
RUN chmod =rx /usr/custom/script.sh
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash -u 1001 someusr
USER someusr
WORKDIR /home/someusr
```

where script.sh (it is in the same directory as Dockerfile) contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
whoami
```

Build the image with:

```
docker image build --tag my_ubuntu_bionic:auto .
```

Then run it with:

```
docker run --rm --name ubl --user=1001 my_ubuntu_bionic:auto /usr/custom/script.sh
```

and it displays root.

How can I run the script as `someusr` ? The `--user` parameter doesn't seem to have any effect (`--user=someusr` doesn't work).

Ultimately I want script.sh to execute in the context of a user that has minimum permissions. The solutions that I've seen on SO assume a linux host.

Versions:

```
Docker version 19.03.5, build 2ee0c57608
OS Name: Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
Version: 10.0.17763 Build 17763
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ownership to the folder where someusr script works it.

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN mkdir /usr/custom
ADD script.sh /usr/custom
RUN chmod +rx /usr/custom/script.sh
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash -u 1001 someusr
RUN chown someusr -R /usr/custom
USER someusr
WORKDIR /home/someusr
```

I've tested this it is displaying 'someusr'.
[image]

Comment: I just tested it and it doesn't work :-( Are you testing on linux or windows? It looks like linux to me in the screenshot.

Comment: If your host is windows server, can you please specify your windows & docker versions?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `runuser` command:

```
docker run --rm --name ubl --user=1001 my_ubuntu_bionic:auto runuser -l someusr -c whoami
```